# how to use sed with variables

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I want to use `sed` with a variable. My script:

```
input_variable="test" &&
ssh root@192.168.7.2 'cd /path/to/file && sed -i "s/this is not/this is a $input_variable/g" text.txt'
```

My script is supposed to change `this is not` into `this is a test`

However it changes it to `this is a` and somehow ingnoring the variable `input_variable`

Anyone an idea?

Comment: It's ignoring it because the command you're giving to `ssh` is in single quotes, so `bash` isn't interpolating variables into it. The shell that executes the command on the remote machine *is* interpolating variables being the `sed` script on the command line is in double quotes, but the variable is set on the local machine, not remote. Read the `bash` manual page section about variable interpolation.

Comment: Your outer single quotes prevent the shell from interpreting `$input_variable`. Try: `ssh root@192.168.7.2 "cd /path/to/file && sed -i \"s/this is not/this is a $input_variable/g\" text.txt"`

Comment: @lurker works, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not interpolating that variable because you are using single quotes. I recommend continuing to use single quotes except for around the variable where you should switch to double quotes:

```
input_variable="test" &&
ssh root@192.168.7.2 'cd /path/to/file && sed -i "s/this is not/this is a '"$input_variable"'/g" text.txt'
```

Answer (score 1):

Environment variables will not be replace in single quoted strings.  Did you try:

```
input_variable="test" &&
ssh root@192.168.7.2 "cd /path/to/file && sed -i \"s/this is not/this is a ${input_variable}/g\" text.txt"
```